# Change Color flowbite-react Tabs Component (Next js)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, flowbite

Hi can anyone help me on how to change the color of tabs in flowbite-react component, I'm using Next js. I already setup as per doc here https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/next-js/

Also I realized that there is no `ClassName` property in Tabs component, so I tried to use the `color` property, but nothing happened

here is the SS:

**No `ClassName` Property in `Tabs.Group`**

[image]

**No `ClassName` Property in `Tabs.Item`**

[image]

**Color not changed using `color` property**

[image]